# Compare strings from two different columns where each cell contains duplicated values and count them in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, character, string-comparison

I'm working with a dataframe that has two columns containing "words" (letter-digit-digit) as such:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c("V01, G30, V01, M05, M05, M05, N98", "J56, K45, L78, J56"),
                 B = c("J45, H67, M05, N54, M05, J76, V01", "S54, F32, K45"))
```

The strings are not always the same length and they contain different words. Some of the words are similar, some of them are even duplicated. What I would like to obtain is three new columns.

First column gives me the number of times each word appears in column A, second column gives me the number of times each words appears in column B and finally third column gives me the number of times each word appears in the intersection of columns A and B. The output should look like this:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c("V01, G30, V01, M05, M05, M05, N98", "J56, K45, L78, J56"),
                 B = c("J45, H67, M05, N54, M05, J76, V01", "S54, F32, K45"), 
                 col1 = c("V01*2, G30*1, M05*3, N98*1", "J56*2, K45*1, L78*1"),
                 col2 = c("J45*1, H67*1, M05*2, N54*1, J76*1, V01*1", "S54*1, F32*1, K45*1"), 
                 col3 = c("V01*1, M05*2", "K45*1"))
```

I do not really know where to start with this, so any help would be much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 3):

An option would be

```
library(tidyverse)
f1 <-   function(dat, colNm) {
          dat %>%
              select(colNm) %>%
              rownames_to_column('rn') %>% 
              separate_rows(!! rlang::sym(colNm)) %>% 
              add_count(rn, !! rlang::sym(colNm)) %>%
              unite(colN, !! rlang::sym(colNm), n, sep="*") %>% 
              group_by(rn) %>% 
              summarise_at(1, ~ toString(unique(.)))  %>%
              select(-rn)


}
df1 <- df %>%  
          mutate_all(str_extract_all, "\\w+") %>% 
          pmap_chr(~ keep(.y,  .y %in% intersect(.x, .y)) %>% 
                    toString) %>%
          mutate(df, C = .)
map_dfc(names(df1), f1, dat = df1) %>%
    rename_all(~ str_c("col", 1:3)) %>%
    bind_cols(df, .)
#                               A                                 B                       col1                                     col2
#1 V01, G30, V01, M05, M05, M05, N98 J45, H67, M05, N54, M05, J76, V01 V01*2, G30*1, M05*3, N98*1 J45*1, H67*1, M05*2, N54*1, J76*1, V01*1
#2                J56, K45, L78, J56                     S54, F32, K45        J56*2, K45*1, L78*1                      S54*1, F32*1, K45*1
#          col3
#1 M05*2, V01*1
#2        K45*1
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use a combination of `sapply` and `strsplit` like this:

```
myfun <- function(x){
  x2 <- sort(table(x), decreasing = T)
  paste(names(x2), x2, sep = "*", collapse = ", ")
}

df$col1 <- sapply(strsplit(df$A, split = ", "), myfun)
df$col2 <- sapply(strsplit(df$B, split = ", "), myfun)
df$col3 <- sapply(strsplit(paste(df$A, df$B, sep = ", "), split = ", "), myfun)
```

Note however, you should convert your columns to `character`: you can do so by setting `stringsAsFactors = F` inside `data.frame`:

```
 df <- data.frame(A = c("V01, G30, V01, M05, M05, M05, N98", "J56, K45, L78, J56"),     
                  B = c("J45, H67, M05, N54, M05, J76, V01", "S54, F32, K45"), 
                  stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: I don't think the brackets are correct because the third column now sums the number of occurences from column A and B for the same word instead of giving the number of intersections

Comment: I think your third 'col3' would be something like `Map(function(x, y) x[ x %in% intersect(x, y)], strsplit(as.character(df$B), ", "), strsplit(as.character(df$A), ", "))`

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not the exact same structure of your output, but I would reconsider reshaping it for data analysis purposes. It is easier to see what you want ("How many times each word appears in column A?") if each *unique* word is a row in *another* dataframe.

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(A = c("V01, G30, V01, M05, M05, M05, N98", 
                   "J56, K45, L78, J56"),
             B = c("J45, H67, M05, N54, M05, J76, V01", 
                   "S54, F32, K45"))

words_A <- df$A %>% 
  strsplit(", ") %>%
  unlist()

words_B <- df$B %>% 
  strsplit(", ") %>%
  unlist()

tibble(word = unique(c(words_A, words_B))) %>%
  group_by(word) %>%
  summarise(n_A = sum(word == words_A),
            n_B = sum(word == words_B),
            n_AB = sum(word == intersect(words_A, words_B)),
            n_AB_2 = min(n_A, n_B))

# A tibble: 13 x 5
   word    n_A   n_B  n_AB n_AB_2
   <chr> <int> <int> <int>  <int>
 1 F32       0     1     0      0
 2 G30       1     0     0      0
 3 H67       0     1     0      0
 4 J45       0     1     0      0
 5 J56       2     0     0      0
 6 J76       0     1     0      0
 7 K45       1     1     1      1
 8 L78       1     0     0      0
 9 M05       3     2     1      2
10 N54       0     1     0      0
11 N98       1     0     0      0
12 S54       0     1     0      0
13 V01       2     1     1      1
```

Please, note that `intersect()` (as in mathematical definition) removes duplicates. As you want to consider duplicates, I also defined the `n_AB_2 = min(n_A, n_B)` column, which does the trick.

Comment: I think your idea works better than mine, it's much easier to visualize. however, i do get an error message ````Error in strsplit(., ", ") : non-character argument````

Comment: It is probably due to the fact you are using `data.frame(...)` instead of `tibble(...)` to create your dataframe `df`. As @Cettt pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57222898/9676054), you should include the argument `data.frame(..., stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` to avoid that your character column are converted to factors.

For this and others reasons, I think you should use `dplyr::tibble` over `base::data.frame`, as it removes a lot of annoying features of the latter.